# Website audio stream relay

Tags: javascript, php, audio, shoutcast, internet-radio

I have a radio station with 50 listeners limit. Is there a way to fetch the streaming MP3 and feed to, for example, 100 listeners? I want in my Shoutcast server to have my website as a listener, then, my website will send the MP3 streaming to more listeners. Some sort of a relay. Relay the Shoutcast output through my website to listeners.
Is there any way doing this using javascript and/or PHP?

Comment: Why not a reverse proxy? https://superuser.com/questions/642666/simple-reverse-proxy

Comment: @FabianH. That isn't going to work.  Such a reverse proxy will make a new connection for each listener, meaning the 50-listener limit from the original server still applies.  The relaying server needs a shared buffer, and the easiest way to do that is just to install another copy of SHOUTcast or Icecast and have it relay.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to fetch the streaming MP3 and feed to, for example, 100 listeners?

Sure, but why would you want to?

At the end of it, SHOUTcast/Icecast are fundamentally HTTP servers.  They simply have an HTTP response that is sent out as data comes in from the source.  All you have to do is proxy the data back to your SHOUTcast server.

There are real challenges with this though.  Unless you come up with a shared buffer mechanism, your PHP script doing the proxying is going to make a new connection for each new listener.  Even if you do have the shared buffer, you now have the whole overhead of PHP for each connection... not necessary.

Proxying in this way gives you no benefit.  Just deploy a second SHOUTcast and/or Icecast server (even on your PHP box if you wanted), and have it relay the existing stream.  These servers are optimized for this use case and have already done all the work for you.

Comment: A little self-promotion:  I run a CDN service where there is no practical listener limit.  You just pay for the bandwidth you use, whether that's 1 TB or 100 TB.  If you don't want to deal with these relays and what not yourself, I'd be happy to set you up with a demo account you an experiment on.  E-mail me at brad@audiopump.co.

Comment: I currently pay 3$/month for 50 listeners, 128 Kbps, 4 Gb autodj storage and unlimited bandwidth. I plan on buying a VPS in the near future then I can setup my entire Shoutcast. Do you offer autodj?

Comment: @XmasterOfficial I'd prefer to discuss it over e-mail if you are interested.  Thanks.  If you go with a VPS, you can indeed set up your own SHOUTcast hosting, and relay from what you have now, or just host it all on your own.